# How To Sum Numbers In Groups Of 2 In Java From a CSV File?

Tags: java

So I have a CSV file which has 2 rows and many columns. And the numbers in each row are separated from each other with comma. And I have sum numbers in each row. For example if CSV is like this;

```
1,2 
3,6
2,5
```

The result must be :

```
3
9
7
```

So I tried and did the reading part. I can read the numbers one by one without commas and did it with useDelimiter(","); Like This:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Read {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File numbers = new File("numberss.csv");
        FileInputStream input = null;
        Scanner reader = null;

        try{
            input = new FileInputStream(numbers);
            reader = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(",");

            while(reader.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(reader.next());
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }   
}
```

and I get smth like

```
1
2
3
6
2
5
```

So how can I sum these in groups of 2 and write them out?

Answer (score 0):

You can read line by line and split with comma then sum

```
import java.io.*;

public class Read {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File numbers = new File("numberss.csv");
        FileInputStream input = null;
        Scanner reader = null;

        try{
            input = new FileInputStream(numbers);
            reader = new Scanner(input);
            String line = reader.nextLine();
            while(line.hasNext()) {
                String[] split = line.split(",");
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(split[0])+Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read a line and then split and then convert into Integer. That's it

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Read {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                File myObj = new File("numberss.csv");
                Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
                while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                    String data = myReader.nextLine();
                    String [] splittedStr = data.split(",");
                    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(splittedStr[0]) + Integer.parseInt(splittedStr[1]));
                }
                myReader.close();
            } catch (

            FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("An error occurred.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```